# Comparing two sql values that are almost the same

Tags: sql

Comparing two sql values that are almost the same.

I know this is simple but I can't think how to do it

I want to do a join or a "select where = " on two values in two tables.
Problem is one table has a filname with an extension and the other has the filename without the extension. I want to ignore the extension and just do my compare.
How would I do that?

I have something simple like this.

```
select thing1, thing2
where tableName.filename=tableName2.fileName
from tableName,tableName2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't use a multi-part `from` clause. Use the `join` syntax instead.

Assuming `tableName` has the extension and `tableName2` does not:

```
select
    thing1,
    thing2

from tableName tn

join tableName2 tn2 on tn.fileName like tn2.fileName + '.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DB is SQL Server and tableName2 has the entry without the file extension,

Try this:

```
select thing1, thing2 
from tableName,tableName2 
where tableName.filename LIKE tableName2.fileName  + '%'
```

Comment: Note that this would match `Cybernate` and `Cybernate Salary.pdf`. Adding the leading period in my answer doesn't make it foolproof (`Adam` would match `Adam.Robinson Salary.pdf`), but it's at least safeer.

Comment: @Adam: Agreed, in that case regex would be a best bet. Because .% would match Adam.Robinson.pdf and Adam.pdf